# XML to JSON Data Format Conversion

Tags: json, xml, data-conversion

I am a student accessing an API with query returning XML data format. I would like to convert the URL query output to JSON, then convert to a DataFrame through Pandas. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: if it's python, use `json.loads(json_str)` to convert it to a dict

Comment: Thank you, Lucas. I will give that a try. Learning as I go!